# Using chart.js in HotTowel , Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, hottowel, angular-chart

I'm trying to use the Line chart [sample](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)  in my HotTowel project, But it does not return any result.
Here is my dashboard code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'dashboard';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', dashboard]);

    function dashboard(common, datacontext) {
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

        var vm = this;
        vm.news = {
            title: 'Hot Towel Angular',
            description: 'Hot Towel Angular is a SPA template for Angular developers.'
        };
        vm.messageCount = 0;
        vm.people = [];
        vm.title = 'Dashboard';

        vm.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
        vm.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
        vm.data = [
          [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
          [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        ];
        vm.onClick = function (points, evt) {
            console.log(points, evt);
        };

        activate();

        function activate() {
            var promises = [getMessageCount(), getPeople()];
            common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
                .then(function () { log('Activated Dashboard View'); });
        }

        function getMessageCount() {
            return datacontext.getMessageCount().then(function (data) {
                return vm.messageCount = data;
            });
        }

        function getPeople() {
            return datacontext.getPeople().then(function (data) {
                return vm.people = data;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

and this is html code which I'm using the chart:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="widget wviolet">
                    <div data-cc-widget-header title="People"
                         allow-collapse="true"></div>
                    <div class="widget-content text-center text-info">
                        <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
                                chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"
                                chart-click="onClick"></canvas> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-foot">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="widget wgreen">
                    <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.news.title}}"
                         allow-collapse="true"></div>
                    <div class="widget-content text-center text-info">
                        <small>{{vm.news.description}}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-foot">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

There is no error message but it simply does not show any chart. Actually I have added the links to js files of both chart.js and angular-chart.js

Answer (score 0):

Depenedency injection have not done for your app.

```
 angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);
```

and also include `chart.js` file after `app.js` file in view.

also change `.controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', dashboard])` 
to
  `.controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', 'dashboard'])`

Comment: Actually I tried that, but it gave this error: [HT Error] [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: chart.jsProvider <- chart.js http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=chart.jsProvider%20%3C-%20chart.js

Comment: may be not injected chart.js file.

Comment: I don't know, how can I find out that is injected or not?

Comment: include chart.js file in head html . like this `<script src="chart.js" .../>`

Comment: did added after app.js file?

Comment: You'll need to include the `angular-chart.js` file *after* the main `chart.js` file as well

Comment: Yes I did, but again the same error, angular-chart.js is already added after the chart.js

Comment: again the same error, thank you man, maybe the problem is with HotTowel farmework, as it does not use $scope, instead it uses 'common'